# Adapter JCA Tuxedo not working

Tags: java, oracle, jca, tuxedo

I am following the "https://github.com/MatthewDavidCampbell/TuxedoJCA" repository code however I am having the following error. Does anyone know what might be missing?

{Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: TPCALL failed TPException:TPENOENT(6):0:0:TPED_MINVAL(0):QMNONE(0):0:Could not find service MY_SERVICE_TUXEDO}

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the JCA adapter either hasn't been configured properly to connect to the remote Tuxedo application, or the particular service is not currently running in the connected Tuxedo application.  TPENOENT is a generic error message that indicates the particular service was not available.

It also looks like that code from github may have never worked based upon this thread in the Tuxedo forums: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2455835?start=0